# Do we really need to put the square brackets?

Tags: notation, expected-value

I just wanted to get the feedback on which one is better considering the random variable $X$ and some function $f$ applied to a random variable.

1. $\mathbb E_{X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)}[f(X)]$
2. $\mathbb E_{X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)}f(X)$

Personally I like the first style better, since it can be tedious to track the expected value in some hairy cases without the $[]$ brackets.

Please let me know which one is better and and if there is any difference comparing the first and the second case. I think there is no difference, but I am not sure.

Comment: Well personally I would write it as the first example, but not for aesthetic reasons. Remember that expectation is an *operator* and as such needs an argument to operate on. I think the square brackets distinguishes this.

Comment: Great, @Kevin, often case I see "people" are neglecting this fact.

Comment: The first option is fashionable in this forum, but both are used by perfectly respectable textbooks.  I personally prefer the second, but often use the first to make myself more understandable, and especially in the "hairy cases" that TESA mentions.  Kevin's comments about _operator_ cut no ice with me: (1), what is an "operator" anyway,  and (2), linear operators on Hilbert space don't  commonly show up with square brackets.